# How to share session in adonis.js in sub domain and main domain

Tags: adonis.js

is it possible to use same session for domain and sub domain? I want to share the users session in main domain and subdomain. how can I do this, please help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

When setting cookie just set it with correct domain attribute (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_path).

So for example, if you have *domain.com* and ***sub***.domain.com, when setting cookies use **.domain.com** (that dot before is very important :) as your domain attribute and cookie will be visible to your adonis auth module on both domains.